# Stretching grid with widgets

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyqt6

As you can see my window looks fine and the two widgets on the grid also look fine but there is no stretching going on.

The two widgets have sizePolicy Expanding for Horizontal and Vertical.
The centralWidget had Preferred for Horizontal and Vertical policy, making this Expanding does not change anything.

The gridLayout seems to be static, in QT Designer I cannot change anything.

I follow [this](https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/pyqt6-layouts/) tutorial and it does not tell me how to do this.
In the code down below I have tested adding setColumnStretch but it does not make a difference. The widget above it; self.gridLayoutWidget, does not have this method.

I want the widgets to show a file tree and resizing the window so these widgets use the extra space is something I need.

[image]

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

################################################################################
## Form generated from reading UI file 'thijs.ui'
##
## Created by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 6.4.0
##
## WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
################################################################################

from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
    QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QAction, QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient,
    QCursor, QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient,
    QIcon, QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient,
    QPainter, QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient,
    QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QGridLayout, QHeaderView, QListView,
    QMainWindow, QMenu, QMenuBar, QSizePolicy,
    QStatusBar, QTreeView, QWidget)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(792, 570)
        self.actionactiontext = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionactiontext.setObjectName(u"actionactiontext")
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName(u"gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 791, 511))
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.treeView = QTreeView(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.treeView.setObjectName(u"treeView")

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.treeView, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.listView = QListView(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.listView.setObjectName(u"listView")

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.listView, 0, 1, 1, 1)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 792, 30))
        self.menuProfile = QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuProfile.setObjectName(u"menuProfile")
        self.menuDatabase = QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuDatabase.setObjectName(u"menuDatabase")
        self.menuFilesystem = QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFilesystem.setObjectName(u"menuFilesystem")
        self.menuOptions = QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuOptions.setObjectName(u"menuOptions")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuProfile.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuDatabase.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFilesystem.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuOptions.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.actionactiontext.triggered.connect(self.statusbar.clearMessage)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.actionactiontext.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"actiontext", None))
#if QT_CONFIG(tooltip)
        self.actionactiontext.setToolTip(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"toooooltip", None))
#endif // QT_CONFIG(tooltip)
        self.menuProfile.setTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Profile", None))
        self.menuDatabase.setTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Database", None))
        self.menuFilesystem.setTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Filesystem", None))
        self.menuOptions.setTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Options", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.  What you have provided goes well beyond the area of your question.

Comment: You're adding an inner layout from the widget box, that's not what those layouts are for. You must set a main layout for the central widget. See the documentation about using [layout managers in Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html).

Comment: thanks @musicamante, it was indeed the layout for the central widget I was missing